# StackOverflow, прекрати!

Tags: дефект, дизайн, 1-апреля

Зашел сегодня на сайт и увидел это!!

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Первая мысль - вирус. Благо хоть подсказка вылезла, но что самое печальное, отключение этого влияет только на одну страницу, то есть переходишь на следующую и снова та же котовасия. ЧЯДНТ?

Comment: С первым апреля! Потерпите денек

Comment: Отключение [пофиксили](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/382067). Теперь должно отключаться для всего сайта сразу.

Comment: @AntonSorokin не пугайте, сегодня воскресенье))

Comment: Comic Sans особенно хорош. Правда, у меня почему-то голова единорога не отображается :(

Comment: Халтура какая-то, бегущая строка вверху сделана через CSS3 transform/animation, а не через <marquee> или хотя бы манипуляции с margin'ом через js )

Comment: у меня тоже только одна задница единорога видна))))))

Comment: @defaultlocale осталось понять, как вернуться обратно в прошлое. UPD: Если постоянно тыкать по кнопке с часами, есть вероятность, что 90е включаться обратно.

Comment: @HamSter, потому что голова единорога - часть меню и чтобы его увидеть надо на три полоски нажать :-)

Comment: @AntonSorokin Включение единорога обратно тоже поправили. Даже попап довели до ума.

Comment: @Grundy, ну тогда надо багрепорт заводить: https://i.stack.imgur.com/hnJri.png

Comment: @Grundy, нажимаю все равно нет головы)

Comment: Каждый раз когда вы нажимаете кнопку "время" - сотрудник "хххх" радуется ещё больше.. (с)ТВ реклама :)

Comment: Мы вернули 2007!

Comment: Новый (старый) SO кстати, неплохо так процессор грузит.

Comment: "К**а**т**а**васия".

Comment: @AnT дыа? Спасибо, буду знать))

Comment: @AnT и все таки вы не правы

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Чтобы вернуться обратно в будущее можно воспользоваться кнопкой:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: А как включить единорога обратно? :(

Comment: @АндрейNOP, очевидно это либо в куках зашито, либо в localStorage, но мне не хватило терпения узнать конкретный ключ, поэтому я и то и то удалял :-)

Comment: наличие сессионной куки tm2019 возвращает обратно в будущее

Answer (score 1):

А мне понравилось. Жалко что на главной нет такого же :)

Comment: Было и на главной, вы, видимо, закрыли уже)

Comment: @DaemonHK, открыл в приватном окне - на главной нет, только на страницах с вопросами.

Comment: либо убрали, либо я вчера был под впечатлением, что единорог атаковал весь стак))

Comment: Есть [скрипт](https://stackapps.com/questions/8287/2019-april-fools-day-retro-theme), который можно применить ко всем страницам.